# C# HTTPS Post with certificate

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

I need help setting up a HTTP Post in C# with Certificate.

I'm receiving an error:

**`"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send'.`**
Thank you.
The Net framework is 4.5

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TrustCertificate;
byte[] bytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(transaction);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlString);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate());
request.Method = "POST";
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + pwd));
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + str;
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
string str2 = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
reader.Close();
return str2;
```

Comment: As you fixed the protocol to TLS 1.2 are you sure the endpoint can handle it?

Comment: i am now receiving this error  
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: i've tried to removed ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; and still receiving same error. i am using vs 2012

Answer (score 0):

The error can have a few reasons. Here is my list for diagnostics.

1. Use a browser (that uses the Windows Certificate Store - IE or Chroms) for `GET` requests, or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for all other HTTP verbs (`POST`, ...) to call the endpoint.
2. Ensure the server certificate is valid (NotBefore & NotAfter) and not revoked. The browser will show errors and provide details.
3. Check the TLS/SSL version on client and server matches. [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (the name is confusing) shows the platform configuration (Windows SCHANNEL) on both, client and server. Additionally there is a [nice PowerShell script](http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2014/10/checking-ssl-and-tls-versions-with-powershell.html) that opens connections with all TLS/SSL versions. If you don't have access to the server  but it is publicly available you an you check what TLS versions are supported by using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html
4. Last but not least ensure the client and the server can negotiate a cipher suite. [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html can show the supported cipher suites too.

**EDIT**

Checking with firefox, the certificate is OK, not self-signed (DigiCert):
[image]

Running a get request against the provided URL with TLS 1.2:

```cs
try {
  var urlString = "https://www.viewmyrecord.com/";
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
  var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(urlString);
  request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate());
  request.Method = "GET";

  using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse()) {
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
  Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Works from here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.

Comment: The 3rd party says that they only allow a public certificate authority (CA) and does not accept self-signed certificates. However, when i checked our SSL (www.viewmyrecord.com), it says "Self-signed".

Comment: @MaKristelMirabel What's the current state?

Comment: Hi,
I'm having difficulty connecting to Surecripts’ E-Prescription (https://smr-staging.surescripts.net/erx/{PortalName}/{Version}?id=
{MessageID})
I have already installed certificate (p7b file).

Does anyone here knows HTTPS Post with client certificate? or have previous experience with Surescripts Network?

I really need help.  
my email address: kristel@friendlysofttech.com

Comment: The WebRequest has a property that can be set. Look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.clientcertificates?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hi @Daniel,

Can you help me with this project? Our company is willing to pay. Thank you.

Comment: @MaKristelMirabel Contact my by mail info[at]lennybacon[dot]com

Comment: Thank you. Will email you before the end of the day. :)